Merging multiple zod unions
type A = A1 | A2;
type B = B1 | B2;
type MyType = A & B & C;

const schemaA = zod.union([schemaA1, schemaA2]);
const schemaB = zod.union([schemaB1, schemaB2]);

const schemaMyType = zod.intersection(schemaA, schemaB, schemaC);
// gives "unrecognized keys" error when validating object

I'm trying to create a merged type using multiple union types. In this case A1, A2, B1, B2 all have .strict() to make sure there aren't unexpected keys. It seems like using intersection() with strict() sub-objects create "unrecognized keys" errors.
How else I can merge these schemas, ideally dynamically, while keeping the strict() for all the objects?
